# wrong to send caption in telegram bot as html format php

Tags: php, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

i have a wrong when using

> parse_mode=HTML

in `sendMessage` is working currectly bot in `sendPhoto` has wrong to show html format link.

```
sendMessage
```

```html
<?php

$txt1="<a href='yahoo.com'>yahoo website</a>";
 $url= "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$token."/sendMessage?parse_mode=HTML&chat_id=".$chat_id."&text=".urlencode($txt1);
    file_get_contents($url);


?>
```

it works true but in `sendPhoto`

```html
<?php



  $url= "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$token."/sendphoto?parse_mode=HTML&chat_id=".$chat_id."&photo=".$photo."&caption=".urlencode($txt1);
    file_get_contents($url);



?>
```

it just show text as caption without any link.
what s wrong in my code?
please help me.
 thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's strange, I can see blue text link in [this payload](https://tg.sean.taipei/payload.php?sendPhoto-b71b6fdc).

BTW, you can try [inline keyboard link](https://tg.sean.taipei/payload.php?sendPhoto-84af3a10) instead, it's more cool than HTML markup :P

Comment: reaaally i am sure it is a funny bug....i think it was working before :(  i need caption of photo :( it is working in sendmessage but in caption of photo it is not shown as link :(

Comment: @a.programmer What did you see?